# Openfire Meeting iOS Implementation

Tags: ios, xmpp, webrtc, openfire

I have set up openfire on my EC2 ubuntu server with openfire meetings installed.
Focus user, test users, group chat and ofmeet are configured using admin console http://myserver:9090/.

Multi users video conference is working properly on chrome browser using https://myserver:7443/ofmeet/?r=testroom.

Now i want to implement this in an iOS app and i have no idea where to start.I did look into some demo projects but still unable to figure it out.

Can someone please help with this? If anyone has worked with something like this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Do you want a step by step tutorial for making an iOS client that connects to Openfire in server side? Please let me know

Comment: Not exactly step by step but i want something to get me started at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following jitsi projects

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-ios

Or

https://github.com/jitsi/react-native-webrtc

Answer (score 0):

The Openfire Meetings plugin is an implementation that wraps various Jitsi projects (such as VideoBridge and Meet). To create a native client that works with Openfire Meetings, it is advisable to use the native client implementations as provided by the Jitsi project.

A good place to start are the React-Native based SDKs that are part of Jitsi Meet:

- https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/ios
- https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/android